# Help to replace a blank space with a backslash and blankspace in a variable in Run Shell Command with Automator

Tags: bash, automator, compressor

Im creating an automator service that transcodes all the files within a folder to a compressor preset by running the following shell script:

```
VAR="/Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -batchname MyFirstBatch"
    for d in "$@"; do
        filename=$(basename "$d")
        fname="$(dirname "$d")"/"${filename%.*}"
        VAR+=" -jobpath "$d" -settingpath /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/Resources/Settings/ProRes/proResHQName.setting -locationpath "$fname".mov"
    done
eval $VAR
```

The problem is that the resulting paths in the string have a **blank space** instead of **backslash and blankspace**, so I want to replace every **" "** in the **d** variable with a **"\ "**.

Also, is there any way to omit folders and only consider files?

Thank you.

Here's a screenshot of my workflow (Get specified Finder Items and Get folder Contents are just for testing purpose, I disable them when using it as a service):

[image: Screenshot of Automator Service]

Comment: Please don't use `eval` like this, it can wind up doing really weird things if any filenames contain shell syntax. Instead, construct the command in an array. See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432352/list-of-arguments-in-only-one-variable-in-bash).

Comment: We do not have enough information to determine the reason for the error.  Do you have a link to the compressor app?  I  ran the script and don't see an issue.  I replaced the eval with an echo and got: 
/Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -batchname MyFirstBatch -jobpath texif -settingpath /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/Resources/Settings/ProRes/proResHQName.setting -locationpath ./texif.mov

Comment: I don't see the reason for the eval.  Just run compressor direct. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson for your suggestion. I'll try to implement it with an array and update my post accordingly.

Comment: Could you specify what the input into this script is supposed to be.  I had to guess.  :-(

Comment: Hi @historystamp I attached a screenshot of my automator service. When using files that have blank space on its pathname or filename I get an error. The command should be formatted with backslash before the blank space.

Current result
`/Users/sergio/Downloads/Compression Test/COMPARATIVO REFERENCIA-MP4 1080p.mov`

Desired result
`/Users/sergio/Downloads/Compression\ Test/COMPARATIVO\ REFERENCIA-MP4\ 1080p.mp4`

Comment: It will be easier to put quotes around the file name. example: fname="$(dirname \"$d\")"/"${filename%.*}"

Comment: To do proper assistance, I need to know where you got the compressor program from.

Comment: fyi: bash process ${} inside double quotes.

Comment: @historystamp Thanks for the help. Compressor is **Apple Compressor** which is installed directly through the AppStore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Compressor.app to test with, but this should work:

```
fileargs=()
for d in "$@"
do
    [ -f "$d" ] || continue
    filename=$(basename "$d")
    fname="$(dirname "$d")"/"${filename%.*}"
    fileargs+=(-jobpath "$d" -settingpath /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/Resources/Settings/ProRes/proResHQName.setting -locationpath "$fname".mov)
done

/Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -batchname MyFirstBatch "${fileargs[@]}"
```

EDIT: If you want to restrict it to just specific file extensions (.mov, .mp4, and .mxf), you can use this instead:

```
fileargs=()
for d in "$@"
do
    [[ "$d" =~ [.](mov|mp4|mxf)$ ]] || continue
    [ -f "$d" ] || continue
    fileargs+=(-jobpath "$d" -settingpath /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/Resources/Settings/ProRes/proResHQName.setting -locationpath "${d%.*}".mov)
done

/Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -batchname MyFirstBatch "${fileargs[@]}"
```

Note that with this restriction, the filename is guaranteed to have an extension, so the `${d%.*}.mov` trick that @user3439894 suggested is safe to use. Also, is it ok to use the the same `-jobpath` and `-locationpath` names? (This'll happen when both the input and output files are .mov.)

Comment: Escaping spaces is the wrong way to do it; an array (and proper double-quoting) work much better. As for the dirname/basename bit, `${d%.*}.mov` behaves weirdly if the filename doesn't have an extension, but there is a "." somewhere up the directory path; splitting it and applying the `%.*` only to the file part handles this correctly.

Comment: @user3439894 I don't have Compressor, but generally programs like that will work on files even if they don't have an extension. For example, `d="/pa.th/to/foo_bar"; echo ${d%.*}.mov` prints `/pa.mov`. Yes, it's a weird case, but I prefer to use robust idioms wherever possible.

Comment: @user3439894 That's a good idea, I'll add it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! One last thing do you know how can I take into account only **.mov, .mp4 and .mxf** files? I tried doing multiple conditions to no avail.

Comment: @SergioVillaKramsky See update. Also, is it ok to use the the same `-jobpath` and `-locationpath` names? (This'll happen when both the input and output files are .mov.)

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Davisson. The edit version worked flawlessly! But I had to replace `~/tmp/logargs` with `/Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor`. How do you use `/tmp/logargs`? You are right about the -jobpath and -locationpath issue as files will disappear when that happens. One way to deal with it would be to add a suffix to the filename, like **-PR422HQ** (which is the codec it's being transcoded to), so that way it will never be the same. What do you think?

Comment: @SergioVillaKramsky logargs is just a little test script I wrote that logs its arguments; I wrote it to make sure this was passing filenames correctly (and forgot to take it out, oops!). As for filename uniqueness: my personal preference would be to keep the transcoded files in a different directory (subdirectory?), but a suffix is also reasonable. But I'd add another filename filter to make sure you don't re-transcode an already-done file. Something like `[[ "$d" = *-PR422HQ.mov ]] && continue` (note: this is a wildcard pattern, not a regex line the other one).

Answer (score 0):

> take into account only .mov, .mp4 and .mxf files

I modified the above script by Gordon Davisson. 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363864/44531

This may need modification.  I didn't understand the -locationpath option. I do not have compressor, so I merely **echo** the last line. Set debug to false when you get tired of the output. I no longer w-locationpathrite code without debug statements.

```
#!/bin/bash
# question:
# https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363854/help-to-replace-a-blank-space-with-a-backslash-and-blankspace-in-a-variable-in-r
# compressor options:
# https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21248?viewlocale=en_KE&locale=en_KE

debug=true
fileargs=()
for d in "$@"
do
    [ debug ] && echo -e "\nProcessing file ${d}"

    filename=$(basename "$d")
    justname="${filename%.*}" 
    # Works for files with no extension
    fileext=""
    [[ "${filename}" == *"."* ]] &&  fileext="${filename##*.}" 

    #  Process these allowed extensions .mov, .mp4 and .mxf 
    [ "${fileext}" = "mov" -o "${fileext}" = "mp4" -o "${fileext}" = "mxf"  ] || continue

    [ debug ] && echo "filename is ${filename}   fileext is ${fileext}    justname is ${justname}"

    # make sure the file exists.
    [ -f "$d" ] || continue

    dirname=$(dirname "$d")
    [ debug ] && echo "dirname is ${dirname}"
    fname="${dirname}/${justname}"
    [ debug ] && echo "fname is ${fname}"

###
### I do not know what you want for locationpath 
###
 fileargs+=(-jobpath "$d" \
      -settingpath /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/Resources/Settings/ProRes/proResHQName.setting \
      -locationpath "${fname}.${fileext}.mov")
done

echo /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -batchname MyFirstBatch "${fileargs[@]}"
```